# How to extract first name and last name from the business card image through OCR.?

Tags: android

I am creating a business card reader application, which uses tesseract API to read text from the business card image, I'am able to extract email id, phone number and website from the string obtained from the ocr but I am not able extract the first and last name from the string

can someone please help me. thanks in advance and please don't mind my english

this is the example of the string i get after processing the image through OCR 
second line is the first and last name

"Rollonhydraulics Technology
Ahmed hussein
ph: +91 9535265478
No. 271, 8th Cross, 4th Phase,
Peenya Industrial Area.
Bangalore - 560058. INDIA
Tel : 91-80— 65456988
Mobile :91-45698 85264
Fax : 91-80-56545558
Email :ahmed@rhcl.com
Website: www.rollonhydraulicstech.com | www.rhcl.com"

Comment: This is a pretty broad question with no straight-forward answer. Figuring out where the first name is will be problematic because it will be in different places on different cards.

Comment: This is very very very tough. Unless you manage to figure out a pattern, for example, your application would know how to identify and differentiate between an address, phone number, a website, and a name, then you can't really know for sure where the name is given the numerous placement and arrangement of business cards.

Comment: thankyou so much for replying...  but there is a app called CamCard on play-store  which has this feature....

Comment: I wouldn't put too much stock in that unless you've used the app on several differently styled cards.  Just because it has the feature doesn't mean it works well.

Comment: I understand but I have used it on three different  cards with different format and it works well.... this is the link check it out  : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intsig.BCRLite&hl=en. and to retrieve email id and phone number I am using regular expression

Comment: @Zakir have you got the answer for this. I need to do the same